# Unable to download files from a method requested by AJAX

Tags: php, laravel

The method create a zip file and download it.The file is created inside `storage/app/public` folder (I ran `php artisan storage:link` to create a symlinks) but it doesn't download.

```
public function download()
{
    $zip_file = 'screenshots.zip';
    $zip_path = storage_path('app/public/'.$zip_file);
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zip_path, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    $path = storage_path('app/public/screenshots');
    $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            continue;
        }

        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = 'screenshots/' . substr($filePath, strlen($path) + 1);
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }

    $zip->close();

    return response()->download($zip_path);
}
```

JS

```
function downloadImages() {
    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    fetch('/download', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text-plain, */*',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('download');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cross-platform download at client browser, You can use php echo string:

```
echo "Here is your download link: " . "<a id="photos_collection" href='". $zip_path ."' download='". $zip_file ."'>". $zip_file . " (" . filesize_formatted($zip_path) . ")" ."</a>";
```

Js 
r is a div for receiving response as responseText:

```
$("#r").html(this.responseText); $("#photos_collection").click();


$("#r").html(response); $("#photos_collection").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The `APP_URL` was not set correctly.

I also changed the JS method to:

```
function downloadImages() {
  window.location = '/download';
}
```

Thanks @pathum-bandara